# Showing that the quadratic form $Q(x,y,z,t)=x^2+y^2+z^2-7\cdot t^2$ is anisotropic on $\Bbb Q^4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, quadratic-forms

I'm looking for help in order to find a prove that the quadratic form $Q(x,y,z,t)=x^2+y^2+z^2-7\cdot t^2$ on $\mathbb Q^4$ can or cannot take the value $0$ on a nonzero element of $\Bbb Q^4$.

I was thinking that it is impossible because $7$ isn't the sum of three square of 
integers, but I don't see how to prove it...

Thanks

Comment: @user127001 $a.b$ is common notation some places for "$a$ multiplied by $b$".

Comment: Yes sorry, it's a multiplication. I will edit.

Comment: (I come back in a few hours, sorry to leave..)

Comment: 7 isn't the sum of three integers???

Comment: Guess he was thinking "three square integers."

Comment: I like this question... I've never really had an excuse to think about indefinite forms that don't have isotropic vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a rational solution if and only if there is an integer solution if and only if there is an integer solution for which $\gcd(x,y,z,t) = 1$.

When dealing with squares, looking at things modulo $8$ is often very useful. What can you say about the solutions to

$$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + t^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 8 $$

? (I've used $-7 \equiv 1$ to simplify the equation)

Comment: The only squares modulo 8 are $0, 1,$ and $4$.
So the solutions are obtained by taking two variables with a square of 0 and two with a square of $4$, or the four with a square of $4$.

Comment: @D.L. : Did you manage to finish the proof with the fact you explained in your last comment? It's very straightforward using Hurkyl's answer.

Comment: It shows that x,y,z,t aren't odd, I think. I will come back in one or two hours to think about it.

Comment: @D.L. : Just to complete on your comment, the number of variables whose square is $4$ mod $8$ (i.e. $\equiv 2,6 \pmod 8$) is either $0$, $2$ or $4$ ; the other variables are either $0$ or $4 \pmod 8$.

Comment: @D.L.: Which, in particular, means that $\gcd(x,y,z,t)$ is not odd.

Comment: Yes, I had finally found, but I haven't had the time to return her before. Thanks you very much for your advices.